# PostgreSQL: Remove element from JSON data

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I am fairly new to SQL and wondering how to remove a specific element from the JSONB data below:

```
[
  {"id":101,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_1"},
  {"id":102,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_2"},
  {"id":103,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_3"}
]
```

In this case I want to remove the object with `id: 102`, so that the end result looks like this:

**Expected Result**

```
[
  {"id":101,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_1"},
  {"id":103,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_3"}
]
```

I am looking to write a PostgreSQL function that receives the id as parameter and returns the expected result above.

Any ideas on doing this with PostgreSQL?

I am working with **PostgreSQL version 15.1** on Supabase.

I tried messing around with functions like `jsonb_array_elements`, but none of these helped me, or I understood these wrongly. Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read more about PL/pgSQL:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/ 
brief summary: 
it creates function `remove_jsonb_object`, takes `jsonb_data` and `target_id` as input parameters. And returns new jsonb data, but without target_id.
Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_jsonb_object(jsonb_data jsonb, target_id integer)
RETURNS jsonb AS
$$
DECLARE
    new_jsonb_data jsonb = '[]';
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_data)
    LOOP
        IF(obj ->> 'id')::integer != target_id THEN
            new_jsonb_data = new_jsonb_data || obj;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    RETURN new_jsonb_data;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can use this function:

```
SELECT remove_jsonb_object('[
    {"id":101,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_1"},
    {"id":102,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_2"},
    {"id":103,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_3"}
]'::jsonb, 102);
```

result output:

```
[
  {"id":101,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_1"},
  {"id":103,"content":"lorem ipsum", "username":"user_3"}
]
```

Comment: @ Karthik S K does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks! This is working well! 

I also had to declare the loop variable (`obj`).

```
... Rest Of The Code ...
DECLARE
    new_jsonb_data jsonb = '[]';
    obj jsonb; -- Add this variable declaration
BEGIN
... Rest Of The Code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following idea might likely not be the shortest and not the simplest possible, but is very clear and easy to understand.

See here the working example according to your data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uOaqC2pD)

So we use `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` within a CTE to split the data in rows. Then we filter out the part with id = 102 because it should be removed.

Then we use `JSON_AGG` to put the remaining parts together again.

So, this will do:

```
WITH previousResult AS
(SELECT value AS part 
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS((SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable))),
newResult AS 
(SELECT * FROM previousResult 
  WHERE part -> 'id' <> '102')
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = (SELECT JSON_AGG(part) FROM newResult);
```

As mentioned above, the linked fiddle show this, we can check every step there.
Of course, you can put this in any function you like, the 102 can be set as parameter.

This will be the function then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REMOVE_ID(id_to_remove int)
  RETURNS JSONB AS $$
BEGIN
  WITH previousResult AS
(SELECT value AS part 
  FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS((SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable))),
newResult AS 
(SELECT * FROM previousResult 
  WHERE CAST(part -> 'id' AS INT) <> id_to_remove)
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = (SELECT JSON_AGG(part) FROM newResult);
  RETURN (SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I added another fiddle that shows the function is also working correctly.

See here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCHMdfMF)

Please note this answer assumes you already stored the jsonb data which should be modified as a column in a table.
If this is not the case, I wouldn't use a SQL function for such purposes, rather do that logic in your application. This should even be considered if you do store it in a column. Generally spoken, this kind of tasks is often be better done without SQL.